# csv to nested JSON?

Tags: python, json, csv

I’m trying to convert a flat structured CSV into a nested JSON structure.  The CSV is generated from SQL which creates multiple rows for each primary id. The CSV is structured as follows:

```
PrimaryId,FirstName,LastName,City,CarName,DogName
100,John,Smith,NewYork,Toyota,Spike
100,John,Smith,NewYork,BMW,Spike
100,John,Smith,NewYork,Toyota,Rusty
100,John,Smith,NewYork,BMW,Rusty
101,Ben,Swan,Sydney,Volkswagen,Buddy
101,Ben,Swan,Sydney,Ford,Buddy
101,Ben,Swan,Sydney,Audi,Buddy
101,Ben,Swan,Sydney,Volkswagen,Max
101,Ben,Swan,Sydney,Ford,Max
101,Ben,Swan,Sydney,Audi,Max
102,Julia,Brown,London,Mini,Lucy
```

The desired JSON output is:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "City": "NewYork", 
            "FirstName": "John", 
            "PrimaryId": 100, 
            "LastName": "Smith", 
            "CarName": [
                "Toyota", 
                "BMW"
            ], 
            "DogName": [
                "Spike", 
                "Rusty"
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "City": "Sydney", 
            "FirstName": "Ben", 
            "PrimaryId": 101, 
            "LastName": "Swan", 
            "CarName": [
                "Volkswagen", 
                "Ford", 
                "Audi"
            ], 
            "DogName": [
                "Buddy", 
                "Max"
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "City": "London", 
            "FirstName": "Julia", 
            "PrimaryId": 102, 
            "LastName": "Brown", 
            "CarName": [
                "Mini"
            ], 
            "DogName": [
                "Lucy"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Both [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29631711/python-to-parent-child-json) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17043229/create-nested-json-from-csv)  have helped but I'm yet to create the correct structure.

Comment: Please post your code here, i.e. what have you tried. Also your csv seems to have extra spaces, and your json definitely isn't json either.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's the general way of doing so with `csv.DictReader`.

Start by loading the data:

```
import csv
import itertools
with open('stuff.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    all_ = list(csv.DictReader(csvfile))
```

Now, you can use `itertools.groupby` to group and process each group. For example

```
d = []
for k, g in itertools.groupby(
        all_, 
        key=lambda r: (r['PrimaryId'], r[' LastName'])):
    d.append({
        'PrimaryId': k[0],
        'LastName': k[1],
        'CarName': [e[' CarName'] for e in g]
        })
```

Will group by primary id and last name, and make a list of cars.

Once you have something like this, you can just use [`json.dumps()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html).

Answer (score 2):

Your data, converted to valid csv is saved in `data.csv`:

```
PrimaryId,FirstName,LastName,City,CarName,DogName
100,John,Smith,NewYork,Toyota,Spike
100,John,Smith,NewYork,BMW,Spike
100,John,Smith,NewYork,Toyota,Rusty
100,John,Smith,NewYork,BMW,Rusty
101,Ben,Swan,Sydney,Volkswagen,Buddy
101,Ben,Swan,Sydney,Ford,Buddy
101,Ben,Swan,Sydney,Audi,Buddy
101,Ben,Swan,Sydney,Volkswagen,Max
101,Ben,Swan,Sydney,Ford,Max
101,Ben,Swan,Sydney,Audi,Max
102,Julia,Brown,London,Mini,Lucy
```

Using pandas to do the heavy lifting, and assuming this valid csv file, this is one way of doing what you want:

```
import json
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

def get_nested_rec(key, grp):
    rec = {}
    rec['PrimaryId'] = key[0]
    rec['FirstName'] = key[1]
    rec['LastName'] = key[2]
    rec['City'] = key[3]

    for field in ['CarName','DogName']:
        rec[field] = list(grp[field].unique())

    return rec

records = []
for key, grp in df.groupby(['PrimaryId','FirstName','LastName','City']):
    rec = get_nested_rec(key, grp)
    records.append(rec)

records = dict(data = records)

print(json.dumps(records, indent=4))
```

And the result:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "City": "NewYork", 
            "FirstName": "John", 
            "PrimaryId": 100, 
            "LastName": "Smith", 
            "CarName": [
                "Toyota", 
                "BMW"
            ], 
            "DogName": [
                "Spike", 
                "Rusty"
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "City": "Sydney", 
            "FirstName": "Ben", 
            "PrimaryId": 101, 
            "LastName": "Swan", 
            "CarName": [
                "Volkswagen", 
                "Ford", 
                "Audi"
            ], 
            "DogName": [
                "Buddy", 
                "Max"
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "City": "London", 
            "FirstName": "Julia", 
            "PrimaryId": 102, 
            "LastName": "Brown", 
            "CarName": [
                "Mini"
            ], 
            "DogName": [
                "Lucy"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```