# CSV to Nested JSON Pandas/Python - 3 levels of nesting

Tags: python, json, pandas, nested

I am trying to convert a CSV that looks like this:

```
purchase_order,sku,vendor,qty,boxid
ABC,BARBY,BARBY COMPANY,10,ABC
XYZ,KEN,KEN COMPANY,14,XYZ
WAW,GI JOE,Cobra,WAW
```

Into a nested JSON structure that looks like this:

```
  {
      purchase_order:"ABC",
      boxes:[
        {
          boxid:"ABC",
          storeloc:"UK",
          items:[
            {
              sku:"BARBY",
              qty:10
            },
            {
              sku:"Skipper",
              qty:10
            }
          ]
        }

  ],
  vendor:"BARBY COMPANY"
}
```

I have something that is very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41843550/csv-to-nested-json-using-python-pandas). I'd prefer not to share the exact code because it has sensitive data in it. However, I am not sure how to add another level of nesting. The purchase_order and boxid need to be the same.

Comment: Why using pandas?

Maybe this is for you? https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

you can use pandas https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html in between

Comment: Familiarity mostlly. Let me look marshmallow a bit more. Thank you.