# Creating a nested dictionary from a CSV file with Python with 2 levels

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, import

I'm struggling with csv import to nested dictionary.
I found a example thats almost perfect for me:

```
UID,BID,R
U1,B1,4
U1,B2,3
U2,B1,2

import csv

new_data_dict = {}
with open("data.csv", 'r') as data_file:
    data = csv.DictReader(data_file, delimiter=",")
    for row in data:
        item = new_data_dict.get(row["UID"], dict())
        item[row["BID"]] = int(row["R"])

        new_data_dict[row["UID"]] = item

print new_data_dict
```

in my case I have one level of nesting more to do. my data looks like:

```
FID,UID,BID,R
A1,U1,B1,4
A1,U1,B2,3
A1,U2,B1,2
A2,U1,B1,4
A2,U1,B2,3
A2,U2,B1,2
```

Result should be:

```
{"A1":{"U1":{"B1":4, "B2": 3}, "U2":{"B1":2}},
 "A2":{"U1":{"B1":4, "B2": 3}, "U2":{"B1":2}}}
```

How would I have to complete and correct the code posted above?

Thx,
Toby

Comment: your input data has the title line twice

Comment: Does this answer your question? [csv to nested JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35969611/csv-to-nested-json)

Comment: @BillHuang no, as the mentioned post does not deal with 2 levels

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using a `collections.defaultdict` that defines itself as a default dictionary recursively, it's very easy to nest the levels.

This self-contained example (which is not using a file but a list of lines) demonstrates it:

```
import collections
import csv,json

data_file="""FID,UID,BID,R
A1,U1,B1,4
A1,U1,B2,3
A1,U2,B1,2
A2,U1,B1,4
A2,U1,B2,3
A2,U2,B1,2
""".splitlines()

def nesteddict():
    return collections.defaultdict(nesteddict)

new_data_dict = nesteddict()

data = csv.DictReader(data_file, delimiter=",")
for row in data:
    new_data_dict[row["FID"]][row["UID"]][row["BID"]] = row["R"]

# dump as json to have a clean, indented representation
print(json.dumps(new_data_dict,indent=2))
```

result:

```
{
  "A1": {
    "U1": {
      "B1": "4",
      "B2": "3"
    },
    "U2": {
      "B1": "2"
    }
  },
  "A2": {
    "U1": {
      "B1": "4",
      "B2": "3"
    },
    "U2": {
      "B1": "2"
    }
  }
}
```

the "magic" line is this:

```
def nesteddict():
    return collections.defaultdict(nesteddict)
```

each time a key is missing in the dictionary `nesteddict` is called, which creates a default dictionary with the same properties (saw that in an old StackOverflow answer: [Nested defaultdict of defaultdict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19189274/nested-defaultdict-of-defaultdict))

then creating the levels or updating them is done with just:

```
new_data_dict[row["FID"]][row["UID"]][row["BID"]] = row["R"]
```

Comment: thanks for your help!!! works perfectly fine. :)
what I don't understand is how the nesteddict is called when a key is missing as it is not in the loop part? or do you mean if I run the program with different input files?

Answer (score 1):

If you're going simple, you can try this:

```
import csv

new_data_dict = {}
with open("data.csv", "r") as data_file:
    data = csv.DictReader(data_file, delimiter=",")
    for row in data:
        if row["R"] != "R":
            item = new_data_dict.get(row["UID"], dict())
            item[row["BID"]] = int(row["R"])
        
            temp_dict = new_data_dict.get(row["FID"], dict())
            if row["UID"] in temp_dict:
                temp_dict[row["UID"]].update(item)
            else:
                temp_dict[row["UID"]] = item
        
            new_data_dict[row["FID"]] = temp_dict

print new_data_dict
```

I just added a new dictionary called `temp_dict` before the assignment to `new_data` so that previous values can be maintained.

Result:

```
{'A1': {'U1': {'B1': 4, 'B2': 3}, 'U2': {'B1': 2}}, 'A2': {'U1': {'B1': 4, 'B2': 3}, 'U2': {'B1': 2}}}
```

Comment: thanks for your help! would love to chose both as correct answers as both are working absolutely fine. I have chosen the other one as it is the slightly more elegant version.